# How to call stored procedure and select the return value at a time on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

on MySQL, I know I can use stored procedure something like this

```
call someProcedure(@return);
select @return;
```

but is there some way you can do it with single query ? like this

```
select @return from (call someProcedure(@return) as sp
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Define Procedure

```
      mysql>    DELIMITER //

     mysql>  CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc(OUT param1 INT)
         -> BEGIN
         ->      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
         -> END //
```

call the procedure ->

```
     mysql>  CALL simpleproc(@a);
```

Show Output ->

```
  mysql> SELECT @a;

      +------+
      | @a   |
      +------+
      | 3    |
      +------+1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think that's what i am saying.. I can use it with two lines of queries but I need to use such call and show output with the one query !